# Updating multiple counters in a single command with pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am processing some text files to search for patterns and count it. As files are very large, processing time is an important issue. I have a python code that gets the counters updated and stored in mongodb. In order to make it work faster I am trying to reduce the number of db operations.

Original version was incrementing every single ocurrence:

```
mlcol.find_one_and_update(
    {"connip": conip}, 
    {"$inc":{ts:1}}, 
    upsert=True
)
```

As this took to long, what I did was to keep the counters in memory, in dictionaries and periodically go through this data to store it:

```
for conip in conCounter.keys():
    d = conCounter[conip]
    for ts in d.keys():
        mlcol.find_one_and_update(
            {"connip": conip}, 
            {"$inc":{ts:d[ts]}}, 
            upsert=True
        )
```

This way the process is much faster, but I see that it still takes very long to update individually every single counter.

Is there a way to launch multiple updates in a single command?

Any other idea to make this go faster?

Comment: First of all index `mlcol` by `connip`. Then try to use [bulk updates](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.bulk_write) it should save on round trips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained by Alex Blex, creating an index and a Bulk execution solved the issue:

```
mlcol.create_index("connip")


bulk=mlcol.initialize_unordered_bulk_op()
for conip in conCounter.keys():
    d = conCounter[conip]
    for ts in d.keys():
        bulk.find({"connip": conip}).upsert().update({"$inc":{ts:d[ts]}})
res=bulk.execute()
```